# Фразеологизм или метафора?

Tags: фразеология

Обживать небеса - фразеологизм или метафора?

Comment: Кто-нибудь знает?)

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется что "обживать небеса" - метафора.
(Метафора – это слово или сочетание слов, используемое для описания предмета в переносном смысле, основываясь на схожих признаках с другим предметом. Зачастую она вытесняет первоначальный смысл слова. Метафора используется не только в разговорной речи, но и выполняет определенные функции в литературе. Она позволяет придать предмету, событию некий художественный образ.)

*Просияли небеса и оттаяли.

Прилетели птицы к нам - с юга стаями.

**Обживают небеса** и скворечники.

Эх,весенняя любовь! Все мы грешники.*
[**Просияли небеса**](https://www.stihi.ru/2016/04/22/1180)

*В Освенциме сегодня тишина.

Не слышно стонов, выстрелов, проклятий,

Хотя почти забытая война

Не выпускает из своих объятий

И тех, кто **обживает небеса**,

И тех, кто на земле еще покуда.

А память воскрешает голоса,

Которые доносятся ОТТУДА.*
[**Владимир Спектор**](https://www.chayka.org/node/7837)

*Но Шагалу невозможно было обрезать крылья, и он упорхнул из России, чтобы **обживать другие небеса**.*
[**Ирина Языкова**](http://www.nasledie-college.narod.ru/Doclad1/Yazyk1.pdf)

Всем ведь понятно, что *обжить небеса **невозможно***. Это яркий пример употребления слов не в прямом, а в переносном, образном смысле.